# I encountered an error in the YAML script when using Docker

Tags: docker, wordpress, yaml

I am using version: '3.8'

```
services:
  mydb:
    image: mysql:5
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: shiva

  mywordpress:
    image: wordpress
    ports:
     - 8080:80
    links:
     - mydb: sqldb
```

Below is the error message:

```
services.mywordpress.links.0 must be a string
```

Comment: ERROR: The image for the service you're trying to recreate has been removed. If you continue, volume data could be lost. Consider backing up your data before continuing.

Continue with the new image? [yN]y
Pulling mywebpress (webpress:)...
ERROR: pull access denied for webpress, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied

Answer (score 1):

If you look at your posted YAML, the `services.mywordpress.links.0` is defined as a mapping (`mydb: sqldb` which is a key:value pair).  The error you posted states that it must be a string.

The string should be the name of the service you are attempting to link, so probably just `"mydb"`.